# Text in Blender Game Engine

Tags: text-object

I have some text parented to the camera to show how many lives the player has.  In the viewport, it looks like this:[image]

But in the game, it looks like this:
[image]

How can I fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: I think ,This is because the text object is treated as a text in the BGE render , there is an option in User_preferences->System->text_anti-aliasing  uncheck it and change the size of the text

Comment: it seem that nothing from its properties is considered as if it is passed as a string to the render engine

Comment: [Duplicate of this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8399/935) You will find links to tutorials that address this in the comments. [This answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14340/935) also explains the issue.