# Text Font as 3D Object in GE

Tags: game-engine, text-object

The standard text looks really ugly in GE, you lose ALL the format settings of your text and end up with a very low quality pixelated render text that doesn't support even a material for coloring, not even the fonts looks the same.
So the solution is to "bake" your text transforming it in a mesh polygon object. whith the command (alt + c - Mesh from Text) But that way you lose the ability to update your text in game, for example using a "string text property"

I found that option in the text settings called "Object Font" witch allows you to pick objects and use them as characters. You just need to name your objects whith a common name. (eg.family-a , family-b and so on) and I got it to work right, I thought that this was the solution for my texts in game. So I started the process of making each character, and half way I come to test just to discover that it helped in nothing. it doesn't work in GE. I got only the ugly text from before and no signs of the polygon characters.

Some one in there knows how to get the "Object Font" to work in GE, or know other efficient methods for putting 3D text that you can update in game? [image][image]

Comment: Text in the game engine should be rendered as meshes with polygons converted automatically from curve objects. No pixelization should occur as far as I know. Could you post some images of the bad results you are getting

Comment: A added a image of the text in game.

Comment: Game engine runtime resolution should only depend on one factor, as far as I know, and that is the render resolution set in the *Render* tab of the *Properties Window*. Text is not converted into some sort of bitmap font, as far as I know, that would make no sense at all. You should also be able to keep it as Text Object directly, I believe, I have [seen some tutorials about dynamic text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiFK6OBgqok) in the game engine so it should be supported. Do a google search and learn some stuff

Comment: Are you sure? the resolution of text in game can vary according to the scaling of the text object, for example, to make a higher resolution text you can scale up the Text an move it far away from the camera to look the right size in the screen. but that way it will cause big problems on my HUD setup. and I don't want to put the HUD in a overlay scene because only messages actuators can be sent to other scenes, and this make too difficult to trade data between scenes to the HUD. instead of that I am going to make the HUD really tiny in front of the main camera.

Comment: Hum it seems you are right, haven't really used BGE in a while. Anyway, apologies, but this seems like a duplicate question. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8399/why-is-my-text-pixelated and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27211/text-in-blender-game-engine

Comment: as far as I know the text object always looked like a bitmap in GE, and the scaling story is true,  unless it was fixed in some newer version, I am using the 2.78b