# Text object alpha BGE python for fade in/out 2.79

Tags: python, game-engine, transparency, text-object

I am working on a "*display name*" with a [text object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_FontObject.html?highlight=text#bge.types.KX_FontObject.text) added from a inactive layer to the current scene.

I startet just changing the [visibility](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=meshes#bge.types.KX_GameObject.visible), then i wanted a "*scaling visibility*". For that (since the base class of the [text object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_FontObject.html?highlight=text#bge.types.KX_FontObject.text) is [game object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=meshes#bge.types.KX_GameObject)) i try [texObj](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_FontObject.html?highlight=text#bge.types.KX_FontObject.text).[meshes](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=meshes#bge.types.KX_GameObject.meshes)[0].[material](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html#bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.materials)[0].[alpha](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_BlenderMaterial.html#bge.types.KX_BlenderMaterial.alpha) but found that there is no meshes.

Then i put a plane.[color](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=color#bge.types.KX_GameObject.color) =[0,0,0] behind the text and meet the colors (text.color=[amount,amount,amount]), `amount = amount + or - 0.02` between 0.0 and 1 to slowly make a "*scaling visibility*" of the text, But this requires the plane as background of the text which i want to not use if there is a way to do it without a background.

Also i have google "bge python text to mesh" trying to found a way to convert the text to mesh so i could add the text object then edit,remesh,show,hide, [endObject](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=color#bge.types.KX_GameObject.endObject) but only found the bpy reference which not work in bge runtime.

And of course a dont want to convert the text to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) since i will unable to change the [text](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_FontObject.html?highlight=text#bge.types.KX_FontObject.text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Animate the alpha of [`GameObject.color`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=color#bge.types.KX_GameObject.color)**

Tested using gamelogic module template, with a mouse sensor on text object. Clicking 10 times makes the text object "fade away".

[image]

```
def main(cont):
    own = cont.owner
    # color vector xyzw  ~ rgba
    own.color.w -= 0.1
    own.text = str(own.color)
```

Comment: LOL I did not think about the color alpha, now i can change the color too, thank you it work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know about the limitations of text objects in the game engine: [pixelated text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8399/2217), [no materials](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14340/2217), does not look the same in game as the real text object, depth buffer issues, etc. and still want to use a text object batFINGER's [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94673/2217) is pretty much what you want to do `object.color = [r,g,b,a]`.

However I would recommend you use the [Font Drawing module blf](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/blf.html).

The example on the documentation page is almost all you need to know to start writing text using blf. Here is a very similar example.

```
import bge, bgl, blf

def init():
    """init function - runs once"""
    global scene
    # create a new font object from external ttf file and store the font indice - to use later
    bge.logic.font_id = blf.load(bge.logic.expandPath('//Roboto-Regular.ttf'))

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    scene.post_draw = [write]


def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = bge.render.getWindowWidth()
    height = bge.render.getWindowHeight()

    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = bge.logic.font_id
    blf.position(font_id, 10, (height - 45), 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 40, 72)
    bgl.glColor4f(.02,.2,.6,.8)
    blf.draw(font_id, 'Hello BGE!')
```

Some key things to note from that script.

- `expandPath('//Roboto-Regular.ttf')` is looking in the same directory as the blend for that font file. Replace with your own.
- The position is in the top left with 10px margin-left. The position's origin is bottom left, so `height-45` brings the text to the top minus the height of the text.
- `bgl.glColor4f` this is how you set the color with an alpha value (r,g,b,a) all 0 through 1 values. (I have it to a semi-transparent blue color)
- `blf.draw` what actually draws the text! to make it more useful use a string type game property.

Comment: _This is what I needed from the beginning?_... it's a case study, thank you!. This is way better if can get it work as i want, but i done some test and was unable to change the text, found that the color need to be in the string and i couldn't  "make copies", etc. the only thing that worked was shadow fade in/out
, i will work on it when i have some time. For the moment ``object.color = [r,g,b,a]`` is my answer.