# Smooth out sharp edges in GE?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have some texts, objects, and other items that give a bad effect when you look at them from a long-ranged distance. They look sharp all over the edges. I notice other games and projects have something in the options menu where you can "smooth out sharp edges." This makes the sharp edges more smooth and appealing to the eye rather than sharp and 'ugly.' How can I smooth out sharp edges in the GE; also, if you can, would it work with a property (boolean) where, when set to true, the edges are smooth, but edges are sharp when false (like usual)? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for anti-aliasing?

Comment: The definition for anti-aliasing basically matches what I want: a technique used to add greater realism to a digital image by smoothing jagged edges on curved lines and diagonals. In other words, yes.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8399/599

Comment: I think what you're talking about with the boolean and all is Level-Of-Detail, or LOD. Someone far smarter than myself may be able to help you with an LOD script to implement into your game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**.

Turn up the number of AA samples in *Properties > Render settings*:

[image]

Note that this may affect performance. Also note that this setting only seems to take effect in the standalone player. Otherwise the *multisample* setting in the *user preferences* is used.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. It should be, can you possibly show me a .blend where is would help? Also, can you do the boolean thing I asked?